# Azure domain configuration

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an APP that was awarded the gorunning.pt domain. It happens that when I call the gorunning.pt domain without the www everything works, when I add the www http://www.gorunning.pt/ I receive the page 404 application not found.

I've already set the DNS CNAME for the application of IP , also tried the url gorunning.azurewebsites.net defined by Azure , created a type A registration.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Your [DNS configuration](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=gorunning.pt%20%0D%0Awww.gorunning.pt%20%0D%0A&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) is correct. However the Azure Web App's front-end doesn't recognize the www sub-domain as it is not mapped in the portal.

You will also have to map the **www.gorunning.pt** to your web app **gorunning.azurewebsites.net** in the Azure Portal. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [dig web interface](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=gorunning.pt+%0D%0Awww.gorunning.pt%0D%0A%0D%0A&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=), it seems the domain has mapped to the Azure web app. However it shows 404 not found. As I know your custom domain maps to an empty web site, so the easiest way is deleting your existed web site then custom domain to the new web site again. If you still encounter the same issue, please submit a ticket via the following screenshot.
[image]